# Deploy each pull request to an app service with a unique URL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Is that possible?

It would be very convenient, to have all branches with an open PR deployed somewhere, where I can have a shareable link.

There are the PR-Branch Triggers, but AFAIK it can only deploy one branch to one environment at the time. And another PR update would just overwrite the state.

**EDIT to clarify what I mean:**

Each feature branch (or bugfix or whatever) of our webapp should be deployed to an app service (or whatever), so when we create the feature, we always have a link to share during development, in which our designers (or whoever) could find issues in early development. At another cloude storage provider, we had something like that and we would always receive a unique link after successful deployment.

Comment: Do you mean that for a certain branch, for each pull request to this branch, deploy  to a different place? or for different branches, deploy to different places when pull request made to them?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I wrote an edit in the question. Basically every pull request should have its own deployed instance of the webapp.

Comment: what deploy task you are using currently? `Azure App Service deploy`?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Sorry for responding so late. Yes, I guess that's it. It's hard to check since I only have access with certain devices, but that must be it. We deploy it to an app service and then provide a command to serve the app. The problem is, that we cannot give the job the right to spawn separate app services, if that is the approach to go for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late but working on this now. What I intend to do:

1. Pull request on selected feature branches triggers task 2
2. Task will create app services via Terraform ([Link](https://medium.com/@gmusumeci/deploying-terraform-infrastructure-using-azure-devops-pipelines-step-by-step-d58b68fc666d))
3. Use the 'app service deploy' task to push the artifact from that pull request to the new app service created in the prior task.

We'll see how it goes

Comment: Instead of maybe creating new app services, you could use deployment slots https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots. I assume it is cheaper than a per/feature app service

Answer (score 0):

If deploying each feature branch to an app service is what you are trying to achieve. 
You can try below steps(Only for classic pipeline view):

1,In your CI build pipeline, Go to **triggers** page, **add** each of your feature branch to **branch filters**, So that each Pull request made to your feature branch can trigger a build.
[image]

2, in your CD release pipeline(Classic view), **add different stages**, each for an artifacts which built from feature branches:

3, for each stage, In the **pre-deployment conditions** page, add an **artifacts filters** to its corresponding feature branch. So that the artifacts from this specific feature branch will trigger to deploy its corresponding stage.

4, Change the  settings and parameters of the tasks in each stage according to each feature branch. So that each app service deployed for each feature branch has its own settings and configurations,
[image]

5,Configure your app service deploy tasks in each stage.

With above steps done,each time when a new pull request is merged to the feature branch, the corresponding stage will be automatically triggered to deploy this pull request to the configured app service.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response! But this is a bit unflexible if I interpret it correctly. This means, that I have to create a stage for each new feature branch and also manually create an app service each time, right?

Comment: You only have to create an app service for each feature branch once, then it will be automatically deployed for the future PRs and merges. I updated above answer a little bit. When a feature branch is completed and deleted, its corresponding deployment stage in release pipeline may need to be deleted too.

Comment: Ok, then I understood you correctly. Thanks for the answer, but that sadly doesn't help my case. But it seems like my request does just not exist on azure, so we might go with our own docker based solution (or something else) somewhere in the future. Thanks for your help!